Ubuntu 24.04 checkinstall fails
I have used checkinstall in Ubuntu 18.04, and 16.04, however in 24.04 I it seems no longer work as expected.
Here is a step by step description (but you need a recent emacs version installed)
clone the auctex package via
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/auctex.git
switch to the master branch via
git switch --guess master
run
./autogen.sh
run
./configure --with-emacs=/opt/emacs29/bin/emacs --prefix=$HOME/ALLES/ --with-lispdir=$HOME/emacs/site-lisp/packages/auctex-git --without-texmf-dir
make
make install
that works
however
checkinstall or checkinstall make install
return the following error.
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 preview.sty /home/oub/emacs/site-lisp/packages/auctex-git/auctex/latex
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/home/oub/emacs/site-lisp/packages/auctex-git/auctex/latex': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:53: install-texmf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/oub/tmp/auctex/latex'
make: *** [Makefile:324: install-texmf] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.


Any idea who is the culprit here?
There is a github page https://github.com/ruxkor/checkinstall
but the last commit is 16 years ago, the issues are not answered. That is why I post it here.
regards
Uwe Brauer

Are you sure the issue is with checkinstall - rather than with your choice of configuration options? Does directory $HOME/emacs/site-lisp/packages/auctex-git exist, for example?

well this directory does not exist, but make install does create it for example, and so did checkinstall in the past. I tried to generate the directory anyhow, but it does not make any difference

Recently, I had the same issue after upgrading to 24.04. The fix is rather easy, only adding --fstrans=no to the checkinstall call solved it for me, i.e. sudo checkinstall --fstrans=no should work.
